# Rails Email Confirmation System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, hash

This is what I have to do in my Rails application, and I appreciate any good insight from anyone.

When a user signs up in my application, I want to send an email to his provided email address to see if the address is valid. On top of that, I want to verify that the email is an address of certain colleges, such as ["US college", "KO college", "NY college"], etc.

I've succeeded in setting up an action mailer, so all I have to do is just adding a boolean `confirmed` and a `college` columns in my `users` table.

I wanted to know the proper and clean way of doing this. Also, if there is a gem that packs nicely all the college names with their corressponding .edu emails, like `{[harvard.edu, Harvard University]}`, I would appreciate it a lot too.

Any advice to implement the function I want would be appreciate greatly!

Comment: are you using any gem for authentication process ?

Comment: I'm using Omniauth to authenticate Facebook users